# how to pass a ruby string to application.js file in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some Javascript to which I need to assign a ruby string.  In this case I have some javascript functions written that require logged in users' email address. I am using haml.

In my application layout file (`application.html.haml`) I could do this and it will work:

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :charset => "utf-8"}
  $(document).ready(function () {
  alert('hello'+ "#{User.find(current_user).email}");
  });
```

but I have a dedicated js file for my app. `application.js` file

How Can I pass the logged in user's email address to `application.js` file from my view??

The following in `application.js` does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert('hello' + "#{User.find(current_user).email}");
});
```

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest moving queries i.e. `User.find(current_user)` out of the view and into the controller by setting the result of that query to `@current_user` - keeps the code base _more MVC_ and in the long run, more readable and manageable.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup your user information in a global JavaScript variable:

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :charset => "utf-8"}
  var user = { email: "#{escape_javascript User.find(current_user).email}" }
  $(document).ready(function () {
    alert('hello ' + user.email);
  });
```

and then off in `application.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('hello ' + user.email);
});
```

And your page should say "hello" twice.

Also, wouldn't `current_user` normally already be a User instance? If so then `current_user.email` should be sufficient and if not, then set then you'd want to set `@user =  ...` in your controller and then use `@user.email` in your view.

I hope I got the HAML right, I don't use it so I'm sort of guessing on the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the application.js code is within a function (ie where you need to refer to the current user's email address). IF so, then why not "read" the data/value from a container tag that is not visible to the user? Your view (which is ERB/HAML/etc - just not js - can then write this container tag with the appropriate value evaluated from your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem to pass variables from controller to javascript.

Install the gem and setup accordingly, then call `gon.current_user_email = current_user.email` in the controller.

Then access that string in javascript like `gon.variable_name`